# Rails flash message not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, actionview

I'm trying to verify a DEA number by calling an action that calls a verify gem.

Here's the view

```
  <label for="prescriber_dea_number">DEA number</label>
  <%= text_field_tag :prescriber_dea_number %>
  <%= link_to "Verify DEA number", dea_verification_insight_reports_prescriber_activity_with_patient_request_index_path remote:true %>
```

Here's the controller action

```
def dea_verification
dea = params[:prescriber_dea_number]
respond_to do |format|
  if PmpCheckdigit.dea_number?(dea)
    #flash confirmation
    flash[:notice] = "DEA number is valid"
    format.js
  else
    #flash error
    flash[:error] = "DEA number is invalid, Expected something similar to 'AB12345678'"
    format.js
  end
end
end
```

When the button to Verify is clicked, no flash message appears on the page

Here's what I get in the log

```
Started GET "/insight_reports/prescriber_activity_with_patient_request/dea_verification" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-30 17:15:34 -0400

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for InsightReports::PrescriberActivityWithPatientRequestController):
```

**UPDATE: I'm changing to a javascript function and a popover**

here's the JS function

```
$('#add_prescriber_dea_number').on('click', function () {
  var input = $("#prescriber_dea_number");
  console.log(input);
  var data = input.val();
  console.log(data);
  if (data == /^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{7}$/ || data == /^[a-zA-Z]\d{8}$/){
    result = parseInt(data.charAt(2)) + parseInt(data.charAt(4)) + parseInt(data.charAt(6)) +
    ((parseInt(data.charAt(3)) + parseInt(data.charAt(5)) + parseInt(data.charAt(7))) * 2);
    if (result[-1] == parseInt(data[8])){
      //valid
      alert('valid')
    }
  }
  else{
    //not valid
    alert('not valid')
  }
});
```

Here's the view snippet

```
        <%= text_field_tag :dea, '', 'data-id-search-key' => 'employer_dea', id: "prescriber_dea_number" %>
        <%= render partial:"/shared/spinner", locals:{size:'small'} %>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id='add_prescriber_dea_number'>
          <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>Verify</button>
```

Comment: You are missing a comma in the link_to, it should be:
<%= link_to "Verify DEA number", dea_verification_insight_reports_prescriber_activity_with_patient_request_index_path, remote:true %>

Comment: Also, consider using shorter route names

Answer (score 1):

I don't think flash messages work for AJAX requests, you should respond with a JSON like {message: "DEA number is valid"} and catch that response with javascript on the browser.

Comment: This is true - flash messages only work with full server requests, not Ajax.  Alternatively, you can generate a "flash like" message in your `.js.erb`.

Comment: I'm going to change the functionality to use a JS function and a popover

Answer (score 0):

You need to create .js.erb (in your case probably dea_verification.js.erb) in the corresponding views folder to update the html where you message supposed to be displayed. It might be already there, if you had ajax functionality set previously. You can update your message with something like:

```
$("#flash_message").html("<%= flash[:error] %>");
```

You might need to add a logic in your js.erb file to handle errors and notices in a different way.

In addition, I think you forgot to declare route for your action (assuming it is called "dea_verification"). Your application is trying to route your request to the "show" action with id "dea_verification". And that is the reason for your error.